# ModelMapper - Failed to instantiate instance of destination

Tags: java, mongodb, modelmapper

I'm working with mongodb so I'm decoupling entities from presentation layer creating DTOs (with hibernate-validator annotations).

```
public abstract class UserDTO {

    private String id;      
    @NotNull
    protected String firstName;
    @NotNull
    protected String lastName;
    protected UserType type;
    protected ContactInfoDTO contact;
    protected List<ResumeDTO> resumes;

    public UserDTO(){}
    //...
```

I'm trying to retrive from db this concrete class

```
public class UserType1DTO extends UserDTO {

    private CompanyDTO company;

    public UserType1DTO(){
        super();
    }

    public UserType1DTO(String firstName, String lastName, ContactInfoDTO contact, CompanyDTO company) {
        super(UserType.type1, firstName, lastName, contact);
        this.company = company;
    }
    /...
```

Like this:

```
return mapper.map((UserType1) entity,UserType1DTO.class);
```

And I get this error about not being able to instanciate `ResumeDTO`

```
Failed to instantiate instance of destination *.dto.ResumeDTO. Ensure that *.dto.ResumeDTO has a non-private no-argument constructor.
```

ResumeDTO is similar to UserDTO, is an abstract class and has concrete classes for each user type. All they have constructors with no arguments.
What is the problem?

Comment: Solution using MapStruct: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/366#issuecomment-283912067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to map a concrete class to an abstract class, this will not work.
You can not use as destination an `Abstract Class`. Why? It can not be instantiated. So you must use a concrete class.

Definitively it wouldn't work a map with an Abstract Class destination:

```
mapper.map(entity, AbstractClass.class);
/*Error: java.lang.InstantiationException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)*/
```

You must use a concrete class which extends the Abstract Class

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
       //
}
```

And then map it to this concrete class:

```
mapper.map(entity, ConcreteClass.class);
```

---

More info:

Due to it is not possible to instantiate an abstract class it will not work in destination properties neither.

There is an issue in Github related to this: https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/issues/130

Comment: That's what I'm doing, isnt? `return mapper.map((UserType1) entity,UserType1DTO.class);` UserType1 and UserType1DTO  are concrete classes.

Comment: What error exactly?  Notice that I have a ResumeDTO list attribute on my abstract class and the error I get is about this attribute `Failed to instantiate instance of destination *.dto.ResumeDTO. Ensure that *.dto.ResumeDTO has a non-private no-argument constructor` is not telling me nothing me about not able to instanciate abstract classes

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, you say: `ResumeDTO is similar to UserDTO, is an abstract class`. So definetively you're problem is related with the abstract class, it can not be mapped (`ResumeDTO`, cannot be mapped because is an abstract class)

Comment: Aaaah, yes. I see it now. Then I can't do the map having this model :( I've tried MapStruct before ModelMapper and it didn't work neither

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you have primitive data types or primitive return types in setter and getter or a parameterized constructor

so here you need to remove following code

```
public UserType1DTO(String firstName, String lastName, ContactInfoDTO contact, 
CompanyDTO company) {
    super(UserType.type1, firstName, lastName, contact);
    this.company = company;
}
```

it will work fine.

Comment: But I don't see a primitive type in this constructor. How will removing this constructor solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

What solved my issue is using typeMap and updating the version of ModelMapper. Please refer the below link:-

[Mapping Lists with ModelMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper-lists)

Using typeMap still gave me the same error. Then I updated my ModelMapper version from `2.0.0` to `2.3.5`, and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same exception. The way i resolved is made a private constructor of the destination class.

```
ViewDTO viewDto = (new ModelMapper()).map(object, ViewDTO.class);
```

The "object" is the domain object and it is to be mapped to the viewDto which is a DTO object to be sent to the client side.

I just added a private constructor to the ViewDTO class.

```
private ViewDTO() {}
```

and this solved my issue.And the verified answer also helped a lot.

Hope this is helpful.